# Trying to delete rows by including a variable in the Range object using xlwings

Tags: variables, range, xlwings

Not entirely sure why this does not work.

```
   for x in ws.range('E2','E'f'{last_row}'):
        if x.value != "CAD":
            del_row = x.row
            xw.Range(del_row,del_row).api.Delete(constants.DeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp)
```

Comment: Deleting forwards is guaranteed to be a problem. As the delete is applied immediately your rows move up in real time meaning some rows to delete are likely to be missed. Run your loop in reverse so deleted rows don't affect the next row to check.

Comment: Try to include more detail about your issue in the question. *'why this does not work'* does not explain what is or isn't happening and what you were expecting to occur. Such questions may end up being closed because nobody knows what 'does not work'.

Comment: And it seems you have already been told not to delete rows top down in a [previous question on VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75699920/i-wrote-a-macro-in-vba-to-delete-rows-when-specific-value-in-3rd-or-fourth-colum). So you should understand why your code might be a problem regardless of method is being used.